# Русская матрешка из методов C#

Tags: c#-8.0

Сидел значит себе хелло воролды писали задумался, а как сделать так чтобы в методе мог быть любой другой метод на месте параметров.

```
static void Hello(){
    WriteLine("Hello World");
}

static void ShowDt(){
    WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
}
```

Два метода их нужно вывести при помощи другого метода.

Comment: [Action](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.action-1)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xIiQn807cMU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться делегатами. Их также как и переменные можно передавать между функциями https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/

Comment: Функция делегата могут включать другие реализации делегатов. Либо можно в делегате воспользоваться фабричным методом, который в зависимости от параметра будет возвращать реализацию класса по интерфейсу.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xIiQn807cMU
во что нашел.
Делегат это сила